# How to create Json object from String containing characters like ':' ,'[' and ']' in Java

Tags: java, json

I have one string from which I want to create one jsonobject

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject json=new JSONObject("{success=false, errorMessage=Application with appId : [randomAppId] not registered, errorCode=102}");
System.out.println("JSON:"+json.toString());
```

BUT right now I'm getting exception due to characters like `:`,`[`,`]` which is inside the string.

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 53
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:222)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:402)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that your string is not valid JSON. Try:

```
JSONObject json=new JSONObject("{\"success\":false, \"errorMessage\":\"Application with appId : [randomAppId] not registered\", \"errorCode\":102}");
```

Comment: @NitinBansal This definitely works. Maybe your problem is different.

Comment: @Henry you might be right as I tested it on Android only where it didn't work