# Passing a nested array from PHP to Java servlet

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, servlets

I have an array $tag which I print using:

```
foreach($tags as $t) {
                echo $t['token'] . "/" . $t['tag'] .  " ";
        }
```

How can I pass this $tag to a Java servlet so in the Java program I can use it just like in the PHP script by using a `foreach` and `$t['token']` and `$t['tag']`?

I'm assuming this has to be done by using a POST method, is it also possible by using GET?

Update
Got a json_array:

```
$js_array = json_encode($tags);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
```

Which returns:

```
var javascript_array = [{"token":"test","tag":"NN"},{"token":"1","tag":"NN"}];
```

I'm trying to pass it to the servlet by using:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">

$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert('ok');

                $.ajax({
                    url : "http://localhost:8080/first/SPARQL",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $js_array,                  
                    dataType: "json", 
                    async: false,
                    success: function (){
                        alert( "succes");},
                        error: function(){
                            alert("false");
                        }
                });

});
</script>
```

However, it returns neither "succes" or "false". It is showing the "ok" alert.
P.S. I'm running the java servlet via Eclipse and Tomcat 8. The php file is on my Wamp localhost. I can acces the url in my browser.
Also, it appears I can't use the $js_array in the javascript which I made in PHP, it says it's not set.

Update: In the chrome console it says:

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/first/SPARQL.
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6 x.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.10.1.min.js:6 x.extend.ajaxresultaat.php?nlquery=Dit+is+een+eerste+tekst:20 
(anonymous function)jquery-1.10.1.min.js:4 
x.Callbacks.cjquery-1.10.1.min.js:4 
x.Callbacks.p.fireWithjquery-1.10.1.min.js:4 x.extend.readyjquery-1.10.1.min.js:4 q
```

Added: `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in the servlet. 
Error is gone now, but it still responds false because I can't acces the PHP $js_array inside of the javascript? Says $js_array is not set.

Comment: have you tried the `success:function(data){ console.log(data) }` it will show you whether you are getting any data within return or not

Comment: what is the value of  $js_array ??

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be to serialize it to JSON and deserialize it back in your servlet. In PHP use json_encode() to encode and decode with any JSON library on Java side

Comment: I tried using json_encode but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is the problem with it? it doesn't encode your data?

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php to check if there were any errors during encode

Comment: Thanks, got the json array working now. Only the passing isn't working

Comment: What do you mean by "the passing" ?

Comment: Sending the array to the java servlet so I can process the array in the java application

Comment: Have you tried `success: function (data){ console.log(data); }` ?

Comment: Hi check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568142/how-to-read-json-sent-by-ajax-in-servlet and http://hmkcode.com/java-servlet-send-receive-json-using-jquery-ajax/

Comment: I read about 1 sentence in before scrolling down to post this as my answer. Array's are the WD-40 of PHP, and json_encode() is the most natural way to serialize 99.999% of arrays,

Answer (score 0):

Since you already defined the javascript `javascript_array` variable at client-side

```
$js_array = json_encode($tags);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
```

Use it instead of the server-side variable:

```
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:8080/first/SPARQL",
            type: "POST",
            data: javascript_array, // updated here                 
            dataType: "json", 
            async: false,
            success: function (){
                alert( "succes");},
                error: function(){
                    alert("false");
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put PHP variable value in JS object use it as mentioned below.

**From:**

```
 data: $js_array,
```

**To:**

```
data: JSON.stringify(<?php echo $js_array; ?>),
```