# Unable to get JSON Object in request to the servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have created a JSON object manually using the data obtained in java script and sent the JSON Object to a servlet using Ajax.

The Object is able to receive but unable to convert to JSON Object again. I am using json-simple-1.1.jar .

I tried

```
JSONObject json=(JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("json_data");
```

But ended with the following error

```
Aug 31, 2015 2:28:13 AM source.main.UpdateDetails doGet
SEVERE: null
Unexpected character (j) at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
    at source.main.UpdateDetails.processRequest(UpdateDetails.java:55)
    at source.main.UpdateDetails.doGet(UpdateDetails.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
```

The output of JSON File sent as request is as follows :

```
{   
    "0":
    {
    "card_name":"Pallela.Manga",
    "aadhar_eid":"1046106160065750110728131521",
    "aadhar_uid":"693228374919",
    "relation":"SELF",
    "age":"43"
    },
    "1":
    {
    "card_name":"KondaBabu",
    "aadhar_eid":"1046106160008020110728125714",
    "aadhar_uid":"996251988555",
    "relation":"HUSBAND",
    "age":"47"
    },
    "2":
    {
    "card_name":"SrinivasaRao",
    "aadhar_eid":"1046106125348220110728131743",
    "aadhar_uid":"609986909901",
    "relation":"SON","age":"25"
    },
    "3":
    {
    "card_name":"Ganesh",
    "aadhar_eid":"1046106160002957110728132026",
    "aadhar_uid":"603873912563",
    "relation":"SON",
    "age":"23"
    }
}
```

Please help me out of this.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

previously I created a JSON String and parsed it to JSON Object using JSON.parse(json_string);

and i've sent the same to the servlet. The servlet trying to read it but as it is got the object as string it is printing as [object object] and while trying to parse back to JSON String giving above mentioned error

finally i got help from stackoverflow from another post related 
[How to read json sent by ajax in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568142/how-to-read-json-sent-by-ajax-in-servlet)

I made a string out of json using the below and sent to the servlet.

JSON.stringify(JSONobj)

The servlet received the string and created the JSON Object successfully using

JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse("json_data");

sorry if my english is bad... Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a literal `String` to the function, not the actual data:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse("json_data");
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it should be:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json_data);
```

assuming `json_data` is a variable that contains the `String` json data

Comment: ooh sorry.. ! Actually I passed requst parameter to a variable json_data and passed the string to the JSON Method. But I am still getting below error..

`code`
SEVERE: null
Unexpected character (o) at position 1.
 at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
 at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
`code`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String json_Data = "{ .....}"; // your json format data
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
 Object obj = parser.parse(json_Data);
 JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;
```

This works fine please test.

Comment: if you still get Unexpected character (j) at position 0 after this means problem is in your json_Data string.

Answer (score -1):

You see only way to get json object from request is by reading lines from buffer reader and appending then to string builder. Then you get full json object request. Then you can parse that json object using getJsonobject or getString. I just implemented the same.

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
         //Gson gson = new Gson();
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while ((s = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s);
            }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());//got the full request as string. 
            JSONObject requestObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
        JSONObject reqjson=requestObj.getJSONObject("Request");
        
        JSONObject auJsonObject=reqjson.getJSONObject("Verification");
        JSONObject getopobj=reqjson.getJSONObject("GetAllOperators");
        String userid=auJsonObject.getString("username");
        String  pass=auJsonObject.getString("password");
        String service_type=getopobj.getString("type");
```

Then using these values i send some response in json format.

```
out.println(obj);//obj is my jsonobject for response.
```